# Python threading crashing on asset load in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I have constructed some code to load assets into a character class. This works fine in a single thread, but I want to have a loading screen when the assets are loading.

I put the asset loading into a function, and tried to make it run in a separate thread. The issue is that it now hangs, and seemingly does not even execute the main thread.

I've kept an eye on the memory usage, and the memory is well-behaved (never goes above 500M out of 1976M, bits or bytes I'm not sure, it's whatever PyCharm reports).

```py
import threading
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def load_assets(screen: pygame.Surface, results: List):
    print("thread: started to load assets in thread")
    appearances1 = {} # some dictionary, Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]
    default_outfit = "office_wear"

    print("thread: instance of game class to be created")
    game = Game("lmao", screen) # crashes somewhere here when running multithreaded
    print("thread: game initialized") # this is never achieved
    # rest of function not relevant
    results.append(game)

def main():
    # ====== INITIALIZE PYGAME ======
    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    loading = create_loading_screen(screen)
    loading.display(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

    # ====== START OTHER THREAD FOR LOADING ASSETS ======
    results = []
    x = threading.Thread(
        target=load_assets, args=(screen, results), daemon=True
    )

    x.start()
    while x.is_alive():
        # never see this print statement!
        print("x is fine")  # want to blit loading screen here

    # if I comment out the threading, and run the following instead, my game boots up just fine
    # in under 3-4 seconds of waiting for the assets to load
    # load_assets(screen, results)

    game = results[0]
    
    # other code here to render the game, no more threading after this point
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return -1
        game.main()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(game.fps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can see the print statements here (everything hangs and we don't even make it to the main thread!)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I feel really dumb now... The issue was my Game initializer was touching the pygame.display() which I already knew it *shouldn't*... I need a nap...